# Django + WSGI + Apache apps fail after idle time

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Using Django 1.11, Python 2.7, and mod_wsgi 4.6.4 in an Ubuntu and Apache environment. I'm pretty sure this is a configuration issue, and I'm happy to provide more information if this isn't enough. In my Apache configuration file I have:

```
Include "/home/django/wsgi-aliases"
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

In the WSGI aliases file indicated above, I have the aliases for my various Django apps written out, along with a specification for WSGI daemon mode. Example:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /EmployeeDirectory /home/django/EmployeeDirectory/EmployeeDirectory/wsgi.py process-group=EmployeeDirectory
WSGIDaemonProcess EmployeeDirectory display-name=WSGI_EmployeeDirectory
Alias /static/EmployeeDirectory /home/django/EmployeeDirectory/EmployeeDirectoryApp/static
```

This all works just fine unless the process stays idle, at which point the page in question breaks, and will not work again without an Apache graceful restart.

One more piece of information: this problem occurs *only* with apps that utilize either LDAP, or the authentication API to our content resource provider. My apps that utilize neither of these have no issues. An example error message:

```
{'info': 'Connection reset by peer', 'errno': 104, 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}
```

It occurs to me that both the LDAP and API connections, respectively, time  out if they are not used. But this was never an issue when these apps ran in non-daemon mode (which I recognize is not recommended and is why we moved over to daemon mode).

This impacts a fairly well trafficked production page and any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are on a quite old version, would suggest you update mod_wsgi version first. Do not use old version packaged with Ubuntu, it is not supported. Once have updated, can then start debugging.

Comment: It turns out, actually, that I am up to date. I originally ran `dpkg -l | grep wsgi` which yielded `ii libapache2-mod-wsgi 4.3.0-1.1build1`. Then I did `pip install mod_wsgi` just to see what it came up with and it told me `Requirement already satisfied: mod_wsgi in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (4.6.4)`. Is there a conflict here, or is `dpkg` giving me the WSGI baked into Debian/Ubuntu ?

Comment: Unless your Apache configuration suppresses the startup messages, you can see the mod_wsgi version being used in the Apache error log. Otherwise need to log value of ``mod_wsgi.version`` in WSGI script file after importing ``mod_wsgi`` module.

Comment: Next thing you want to do is ensure setting ``LogLevel info`` in Apache configuration so mod_wsgi logs more about daemon process restarts etc. Then add to ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` the option ``request-timeout=30``. Your problem may be your request handlers getting stuck. That option will ensure stuck processes are restarted, and log a Python stack trace of where when doing so so that can debug.

Comment: My Apache log says that my `mod_wsgi` is compiled against Python 2.7.11, whereas I'm running 2.7.12. Is a small version discrepancy like that generally impactful?

Comment: Also, I ran `mod_wsgi-express module-config` which indicated two items that I did not have in my Apache configuration: `LoadModule wsgi_module [long path to dist-packages here]` and `WSGIPythonHome "/usr"`. I added both of these to my configuration.

Comment: Finally, I added `request-timeout` to `WSGIDaemonProcess` to no avail.

Comment: Are you loading any Apache module for authentication that uses LDAP? Or are you using PHP in same Apache and it is loading a LDAP module? If you are they could be loading a LDAP library first which is different version to what Python LDAP module was compiled for, and thus it is failing.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this ancient thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/iYaaM-qjPg4) which you participated in, which seems exactly like my problem, but I can't even say for sure if my configuration matches what you're asking. There is PHP code in our ecosystem that I have no involvement with, not sure if it utilizes LDAP.

Comment: The problem with PHP is that it loads modules for just about everything even if you aren't using them.

Comment: Anyway, lets revisit where you said "This all works just fine unless the process stays idle, at which point the page in question breaks, and will not work again without an Apache graceful restart.". I missed possible meaning of this. You are saying it does work initially but then stops working if application is not used for a while. If yes, this could be caused by code caching connection and not re-establishing when LDAP server drops it, or something like that.

Comment: Suggest try adding ``inactivity-timeout=60`` to ``WSGIDaemonProcess``. This will cause a process restart if no requests for 60 seconds.

Comment: I currently have `request-timeout=30` attached to all of my `WSGIDaemonProcess` statements in my aliases file. Looking at the mod_wsgi documentation, `request-timeout` and `inactivity-timeout` seem to have a similar effect, no?

Comment: No, they are different. The ``request-timeout`` is to deal with stuck requests and recover the process. The ``inactivity-timeout`` is to restart a process when it has no requests at all for a period of time. The latter doesn't trigger if there are running requests.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense and I will try it. Something else of note, can you shed light on whether `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` is necessary in my Apache configuration while running WSGI in daemon mode? I am seeing conflicting ideas about this in various places online. I currently have it set in my port 443 `<VirtualHost>` section.

Comment: If you are only running the one web site in embedded mode, or delegating each WSGI application when hosting more than one to separate daemon process groups, you should always use ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}``. This avoids problems with third party packages for Python with C extensions that aren't implemented properly to work in sub interpreters. If don't use it, those extension modules can cause deadlocks or crashes. So safest thing to do is use it.

Comment: The switch to `inactivity-timeout` _seems_ to have cured the problem. I think that we are still unclear as to why all this was happening in the first place though. It looks like LDAP interacts with the daemon process in some manner that isn't obvious. With `inactivity-timeout=300` in place, I can hit a page, let it sit for five minutes and the page's process will move to the top of the `ps -ef` listing. My concern is that if a page is getting hammered, `inactivity-timeout` never triggers, the process never restarts, and LDAP will again break.

Comment: If the code in your process is going into a tight loop, then add this code so you can trigger dumping of Python stack tracers to see where it is executing. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/debugging-techniques.html#extracting-python-stack-traces